# add class to an acf page

Tags: php, wordpress, class, advanced-custom-fields

I want to apply css on the rows in a specific  page, but all the pages have the same row-classes.
So I taught its better to add a specific class to the page and then apply the css on it.
I use ACF and I don't know how to add class to this page.
I tried different codes into function.php with no luck.
Exp:

```
function be_portfolio_archive_body_class( $classes ) {
  
  $classes[] = 'sortiment';
  return $classes;

}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'be_portfolio_archive_body_class' );
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/

Comment: @SunnyParsana: Thank you, it works, but I want this className for a specific page. do you know how?

Comment: Yes Dear I know check this link (https://www.isitwp.com/add-custom-body-class-for-specific-pages/) https://prnt.sc/VdGcv1HX38jT